# MysQL RegExp - Advanced usage

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table `reservation` that having a column with un-normalized data like

```
6-1,7-2,8-3,9-4,12-7,
```

the `6` in the `6-7` is referring an id of another table `packages`. `7` is `quantity` for `6` and the packages are separated by the `,`.

And now I want to `JOIN` these two tables using `REGEXP`. The row having above cell (`6-1,7-2,8-3,9-4,12-7,`) will retrieve `package` rows for `6, 7, 8, 9 and 12` package ids.

Please help me.

**Answer:**

Thanks @HamZa

But unfortunately I have to stick with current database. It's not mine and the system is a running one.

This is the solution. It may helpful anyone who face the same kind of situation.

```
SELECT reservation.*, package.name PackageName FROM reservation, package WHERE reservation.packages REGEXP CONCAT('', package.id,'-[0-9]');
```

And never do this kind of stupid database design.

Comment: You have a design problem. Attack the root of the problem: redesign your database if possible. I recommend [this book *SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming*](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) Hacking with SQL regex is tough and expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Though the normalization is bad, unfortunately I have to stick with current database. It's not mine and the system is a running one.

This is the solution. **It may helpful anyone who face the same kind of situation.**

```
SELECT reservation.*, package.name PackageName 
FROM reservation, package 
WHERE reservation.packages REGEXP CONCAT('', package.id, '-[0-9]');
```

And never do this kind of stupid database design.